# QA in Stored Procedure using Case statement and a variable, keep getting incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a stored procedure to append from two source tables to a master table while calculating some of the columns. Before I can append from source 1 to the master table I have to update column `Service_Element` so that downstream procedures can join tables correctly.

After I update I want to create some QA, so that if the columns didn't update correctly, it will stop the procedure (this cause me and my team to rerun our entire process last month because the error was not caught until after we ran everything)

Below is the code I have so far.

```
declare @secount as int

set @secount = (
   select COUNT(*) 
   from (
      select 
         datepart(year, ReportingMonth) as full_year, 
         Service_Element, 
         sum(Quantity) as amount 
      from tbl_VolumeImport  
      where (Service_Element like '%Windows%' or Service_Element like '%Linux%' ) 
        and datepart(year, ReportingMonth) = '2014'
      group by datepart(year, ReportingMonth), Service_Element) as E)   

select case 
    when @secount = 0 then print 'no errors' else print 'can not proceed'
end as Error
```

This is the error that I get:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'print'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

Also I would like to change the else to `RETURN` so that it stops the rest of the procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
if @secount = 0 
begin
   print 'no errors'
end
else
begin
   print 'can not proceed'
   return
end
```

*more code....*